# cannot define a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I am trying to get data from a JSON file into an angular app, the thing is I will be using this file as a local database and it will contain more than one array so I have to name the array but when I try to define it the vs points it out as an error.

Here's the array

```
var historybooks = [
{
    "name" : "book1",
    "id" : "his-1",
    "author" : "omar",
    "discription" : "lorem ipsum dolor ....",
    "image" : "./assets/books-images/book1.png"
}
]
```

vs error "Expected a JSON object, array or literal."

I also tried with let instead of var and get the same error.

Comment: u can't "name" an array in json file. what you cn do is add a property to object as an identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare a variable inside a JSON.Remove the declaration.

If you want to declare more array's you can do this in the same file:

```
{
"array1":[{"key":"value","key":"value"}],
"array2":[{"key":"value","key":"value"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code if the file is a **JS** file:-

```js
export var historybooks = [
{
    "name" : "book1",
    "id" : "his-1",
    "author" : "omar",
    "discription" : "lorem ipsum dolor ....",
    "image" : "./assets/books-images/book1.png"
}
]
```

If you want to name the file as **.json**, then use the below code:-

```js
[
{
    "name" : "book1",
    "id" : "his-1",
    "author" : "omar",
    "discription" : "lorem ipsum dolor ....",
    "image" : "./assets/books-images/book1.png"
}
]
```

You can make an Ajax request to fetch the `.json` file.

Comment: second one it would be only one array i want to add more than one ,, is it possible ? , cause i want to use as a DB

Comment: If you are making it a .json file, you can make an object and then define different arrays in it

Comment: Nice alternative for including JS files, but just keep in mind that [**export**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Browser_compatibility) is not supported in older browsers such as Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @chŝdk but would it not work since it is an angular app and would be compiled into native JS code using webpack?

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can't write declarations, inside a JSON file all that you can do is write your JSON object or array directly on the file.

That's why you are getting the error:

> "Expected a JSON object, array or literal."

Because you are writing JavaScript code inside of your JSON file, remove the declaration part:

```
[
{
    "name" : "book1",
    "id" : "his-1",
    "author" : "omar",
    "discription" : "lorem ipsum dolor ....",
    "image" : "./assets/books-images/book1.png"
}
]
```

Comment: so if i want more than one array i need to make more than one JSON file

Comment: @OmarMohmedAbdelhady Yes, you need to make each array in a separate file, you can't use `var historybooks =` declarations.

Comment: @OmarMohmedAbdelhady Great, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the code after this is being interpreted as an index into the array or something like that
Try adding a semi-colon after the array :

```js
var historybooks = [
  {
      "name" : "book1",
      "id" : "his-1",
      "author" : "omar",
      "discription" : "lorem ipsum dolor ....",
      "image" : "./assets/books-images/book1.png"
  }
]; // <= here
```

Comment: no i had to make it in separate file or an object of arrays

Answer (score 0):

Just remove decalartion part of your json , and your good to go something like this.

```
   [
    {
    "Neymary": "pleaseStopDiving"
    }
   ]
```